# How to lock LayoutItem layers in QGIS 3.0 using python?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I am using the python console to interact with QGIS 3.0 and have accessed the layout manager using:

```
lomgr = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager()
lo = lomgr.layouts()[0]
myMapItem = lo.itemById('myMapItem')
```

I need to lock the layers programmatically as I would if I were using the LayoutManager UI (e.g., select the item, go to Item Properties tab, and check/uncheck the 'Lock Layers' checkbox).  I can't find any way of doing this from the documentation (https://python.qgis.org/api/classQgsLayoutItem.html).

Answer (score 1):

Call `setLayers([layer1,layer2,...])` (https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Layout/QgsLayoutItemMap.html#qgis.core.QgsLayoutItemMap.setLayers) on the map item:

```
lomgr = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager()
lo = lomgr.layouts()[0]
myMapItem = lo.itemById('myMapItem')
myMapItem.setLayers([layer1, layer2])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I had tried that approach but setLocked() locks the LayoutItem itself from mouse interactions.  I am trying to lock the layoutItem layers which is different.  I have found the layer lock setting within the template XML but there doesn't appear to be a python function to perform the layer locks.  I'll post more once I have more time to test.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

sure it is too late but others might find it useful:
The methods you were looking for were probably:

```py
setLayers()
```

and

```py
storeCurrentLayerStyles()
```

These are methods of class QgsLayoutItemMap.
Consider you have a map object called map1 of a QGIS - Project called project1.
To lock all layers of map1 of the current layer tree you could:

```py
map1.setLayers(project1.mapLayers().values())
```

and then

```py
map1.storeCurrentLayerStyles()
```

To release the layers you could e.g. simply use an empty dictonary in the setLayers method:

```py
map1.setLayers({})
map1.storeCurrentLayerStyles()
```

Hope it helped