# Locking layer styles in QGIS Print Layout using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, print-composer, style

I try to make a print-layout consisting of 2 maps-items. I only use one layer, but I want to picture it in different styles.

First, as it is when loaded, and on the second map in another style (which I load from a file). I used a template for the layout production (https://opensourceoptions.com/blog/pyqgis-create-and-print-a-map-layout-with-python/) an adapted it. Then I red the advice from bbsea ([How to lock LayoutItem layers in QGIS 3.0 using python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285917/how-to-lock-layoutitem-layers-in-qgis-3-0-using-python)) and used `map.storeCurrentLayerStyles()`, still it is not working.

To put it in pictures, this is what I want:

[image]

but this is what I get:

[image]

Here is the code I use:

```py
from qgis.PyQt import QtGui

layer_list = iface.mapCanvas().layers()
project = QgsProject.instance()
manager = project.layoutManager()
layoutName = 'Test1'
layouts_list = manager.printLayouts()
layout = QgsPrintLayout(project)
layout.initializeDefaults()
layout.setName(layoutName)
manager.addLayout(layout)
layer = layer_list[0]

# first map:
map = QgsLayoutItemMap(layout)
map.setRect(60, 20, 60, 20)
ms = QgsMapSettings()
ms.setLayers([layer]) 
rect = QgsRectangle(ms.fullExtent())
rect.scale(1.0)
ms.setExtent(rect)
map.setExtent(rect)
map.setBackgroundColor(QColor(255, 255, 255, 0))
layout.addLayoutItem(map)
map.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(5, 5, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
map.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(90, 90, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
map.storeCurrentLayerStyles()

# second map:
map2 = QgsLayoutItemMap(layout)
map2.setRect(60, 20, 60, 20)
ms2 = QgsMapSettings()
layer.loadNamedStyle('/home/..../style.qml')
layer.triggerRepaint()
ms2.setLayers([layer])
rect2 = QgsRectangle(ms2.fullExtent())
rect2.scale(1.0)
ms2.setExtent(rect2)
map2.setExtent(rect2)
map2.setBackgroundColor(QColor(255, 255, 255, 0))
layout.addLayoutItem(map2)
map2.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(95, 95, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
map2.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(90, 90, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
map2.storeCurrentLayerStyles()

layout = manager.layoutByName(layoutName)
exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
fn = '/home/c/mapTest.pdf'
exporter.exportToPdf(fn, QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings())
```

How can I lock the layer-style in?

Comment: Did you have a look at map themes? See: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html?#configuring-map-themes

Comment: Not really. I would like to code it... it is part of a bigger project.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but still the 1.map is changing...

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that I can't really provide an intelligent or scientific explanation of the problem here, because I tried modifying your code and I was not able to get a satisfactory result.

But it works for me with the following code snippet which I tested on a similar data set to what you have shown.

```py
project = QgsProject.instance()
layout = QgsPrintLayout(project)
layout.initializeDefaults()
layout.setName('Test1')
project.layoutManager().addLayout(layout)

layer_list = iface.mapCanvas().layers()
layer = layer_list[0]

map1 = QgsLayoutItemMap(layout)
map1.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(5,50, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
map1.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(125,85, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
map1.setExtent(layer.extent())
map1.setLayers([layer])
layout.addLayoutItem(map1)


map1.storeCurrentLayerStyles()
map1.setKeepLayerSet(True)
map1.setKeepLayerStyles(True)


map2 = QgsLayoutItemMap(layout)
map2.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(150,50, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
map2.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(125,85, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))

#change path to your own saved style file
layer.loadNamedStyle('C:\\Users\\Ben\\Desktop\\Layer_styles\\test_style.qml')
layer.triggerRepaint()
map2.setExtent(layer.extent())
map2.setLayers([layer])
layout.addLayoutItem(map2)
```

The result is:

[image]

The required api call seems to be:

```py
map1.setKeepLayerStyles(True)
```

Because if I just comment out that single line, the stored style for map 1 is not locked and changes to follow the new style applied as in the problem you describe.

Comment: It works : ) Thank you VERY much!